Setting xrange starting 2 days back
I am trying to draw a few graphs relative to a time axis that should automatically draw anything from the samle starting 2 days back since time of plotting. I couldn't figure it out with gnuplot's mechanics, so did this
set xrange [system("date -d 'now-2days' '+%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'"):]

but it does not seem to see output of the system() as a string
gnuplot> show xrange

        set xdata time
        set xrange [ "0021-06-21 00:00:00" : * ] noreverse writeback  # (currently ["0021-06-21 00:00:00":"2258-01-03 00:00:00"] )

What am I doing wrong?

Short answer: gnuplot has the function time(0) and the day has 24*3600=86400 seconds, check help time.
In your case it might be easier if you are not using the set xdata and set timefmt syntax, but plotting in seconds via timecolumn() and set format x "..." timedate. Check help timecolumn.
In the following script some test data is created which has the following format, hence y-data is in column 3.
19-06-2024 17:17:20      0.723499
19-06-2024 19:17:20      0.887003
19-06-2024 21:17:20      0.539661
19-06-2024 23:17:20      0.294528
20-06-2024 01:17:20      0.00987316
20-06-2024 03:17:20      0.915195
20-06-2024 05:17:20      0.836616

Script:
### set time range starting from 2 days from now
reset session

SecsPerDay = 86400
fmt        = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"

# create some test data
set table $Data
    plot '+' u (strftime(fmt,time(0)+SecsPerDay*($0/12-4))):(rand(0)) w table
unset table

set xrange[time(0)-2*SecsPerDay:]
set format x "%d-%m" timedate

plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,fmt)):3 w lp pt 7 lc "red"
### end of script

Result: (plotted 23-06-2024 19:17:00)


Yep, it seems to work... I never used timecolumn() before, didn't really understand what it is for... :-)
